# Nested Jquery Selectors current element within a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Problem: I want to select all children + grandchildren of the current element.

Sample HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS Loop goes through every div class A.
I want to select B in within this Loop and only the B of the current div class A.

```
$(".a").each(function(){
// SELECT div class B here and only the B of the current A
});
```

Why isn't this working?

```
   $(".a").each(function(){
     $(this).contents().filter('.b').each(function(){
      console.log("Test");
     });
    });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: `$('.a .b').each(function() { $(this).closest('.b').addClass('selected').end().addClass('selected'); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation didn't worked as the method `.filter()` matches element at same level. You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) since `.b` is descendant of `.a`.

```
$(".a").each(function() {
    $(this).find('.b').each(function() {
        console.log("Test");
    });
});
```

*OR*, You can directly use [`Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)`](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$(".a .b").each(function() {
    console.log("Test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find "B" within the A:

```
 $(".a").each(function(){
     $(this).find('.b').each(function(){
     console.log("Test");
 });
});
```